# How to stop fixed header overlapping scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm currently face an issue with my fixed 100% width header overlapping the scroll bar. I need the overflow-x:hidden as I have CSS animations which fly in and cause horizontal scrollbars.

Here is the JS Fiddle Code: [https://js fiddle.net/kanwu3mc/1/](https://js%20fiddle.net/kanwu3mc/1/)

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem

```
html, body{
  ...
  height:100%;
  ...    
}
```

change to

```
html, body{
    ...
    min-height:100%;
    ...    
}
```

It's incorrect to fix the height of html and body that way. Only min-height allowed in this case.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to add the following to your scroll event callback:

```
header.style.width = `${document.body.scrollWidth}px`;
```

However, I would suggest that you consider implementing a largely CSS solution for such tasks.  Consider making the header `position: sticky` and adding a new teal color class to the element when the scroll event is triggered.